# Modelling folder structure in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to save an hierarchical folder structure into a SQL database. The class would like this:

```
public class Folder
{
    public Folder()
    {
        Children = new List<Folder>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set;  }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Folder Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Folder> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map it using Entity Framework Core:

```
builder.Entity<Folder>()
       .HasKey(i => i.Id);

// Relation 1
builder.Entity<Folder>()
       .HasMany(e => e.Children)
       .WithOne(e => e.Parent)
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);

// Relation 2
builder.Entity<Folder>()
       .HasOne(f => f.Parent)
       .WithMany(f => f.Children)
       .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

If I try to update the database, I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Folders_Folders_ParentId' on table 'Folders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean openConnection, Boolean closeConnection)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean manageConnection)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0()
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> ClientConnectionId:f0c08167-fba7-4afa-baf0-45909e9a1f4b
>   Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16
>
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Folders_Folders_ParentId' on table 'Folders' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. 
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I also tried mapping it without the 'Relation 2', it works but then when I load the items from database they return as single items with the Children property not set.

What is the correct way of storing such kind of data?

Comment: Why not create the database and map with Entity Reverse Engineer?  That would be way easier.     https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Comment: Because while developing my model will be changed but mainly extended and I would prefer to have the EF create the database instead of updating it manually. I'm also new to EF and this is mainly an exercise for learning Code First approach

Comment: In that case, I recommend creating the database and still using Entity Tools to reverse engineer and see where you went wrong. It's really hard for us to answer this question without knowing your DB schema.

Comment: Why not reverse engineer the database correctly with https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838, then delete the generator and switch to migrations going forward.

Comment: @SimonHughes lol awesome. In case the first link doesnt work :)

Comment: Driving the point home :-)

Comment: You don't need an extension to do that. You need a one line command: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#reverse-engineer-your-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should't need any mapping configuration. The model definition is enough on its own for migrations to generate the correct table structure, which will be a PK field called `Id`, and a nullable FK field called `ParentId`.

The principal behind this in EF Core is the same as it is in EF 6. For more information: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management