# Entity Framework Self Referencing Table, Deleting causes constraint conflict

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to implement a folder hierarchy structure in EF. Now I have searched this to find a solution and found the following:

[Modelling folder structure in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790307/modelling-folder-structure-in-entity-framework-core)

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/255/entity-framework-recipe-hierarchical-data-management

However, I am facing two issues. One is if we set 
    WillCaseCadeOnDelete(false)

I'll get the following error.
    The DELETE statement conflicted with the SAME TABLE REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Folders_dbo.Folders_ParentFolderId". The conflict occurred in database "CMSDatabase", table "dbo.Folders", column 'ParentFolderId'.

if I set WillCaseCade on delete to true, I'll get an error about "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths".

Here is the code

```
public class Folder
{

    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = ("Parent Folder"))]
    public int? ParentFolderId { get; set; }


    public virtual Folder Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> Children { get; set; }



}
```

I have also set the configuration for this.

```
HasOptional(e => e.Parent).WithMany(e => e.Children).HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentFolderId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

What really want to do is be able to delete all sub folders, so if we have a structure like

```
Products > Laptops > Intel
```

if products is deleted all sub folders are deleted to. Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to load all dependent entities into the context and set there state to deleted then EF can issue delete statements for them.

Comment: so basically i would need to get child folders first and delete them before deleting parent?

Comment: Yeah basically, just load them in and set them all to deleted. Not before, just at the same time. If you know what exists you could attach them to save on loading.